# Unity Button OnClick working on PC but not working on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, button, onclick

the idea of the function is that it changes one canvas for another. The problem is that it works perfectly on PC, but on android the button receives the click (because it changes colour) but it doesn't execute the function.
Any help? Thanks :)

[Button's inspector tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMBXs.png)
[Button on Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBBrG.png)

```
public void SwapToCanvas(int n)
{
    if (controller != null)
    {
        Destroy(controller.LastGuia.gameObject);
    } else
    {
        controller = GameObject.Find("GuiaController").GetComponent<GuiaController>();
        Destroy(controller.LastGuia.gameObject);
    }
    
    controller.GetComponent<GuiaController>().LastGuia = Instantiate(SwapTo[n]);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you have assigned OnClick's method recently and didn't save the scene? Or maybe you have 2 scenes and the one you build is outdated? If that's not the case, have you tried debugging it on the device via Android Studio?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response. I'm learning to program and I didn't know I could debug with android studio. Apparently a null was generated in the apk version that did not occur in the pc version. Fixed it! Thank you very much!